# 2 grep in if statement

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Anyone can tell me what will be the problem?i know that this is a half sec problem but pls help:) `egrep "first" a.sh && egrep "second" a.sh` works, a.sh contains first,second,third etc.. Thx!

```
 if [[ egrep "first" a.sh && egrep "second" a.sh ]]; then
 echo "success"
 fi
```

Comment: dont know, just find an example. wont work without too, not the -n is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be what you are looking to do:

```
found_1=$(egrep "first" a.sh)
found_2=$(egrep "second" a.sh)

if [[ -n "$found_1" ]] && [[ -n "$found_2" ]]; then
    echo "success"
fi
```

Comment: You only need to examine the exit statuses: `egrep -q first a.sh; rc1=$?; egrep -q second a.sh; rc2=$?; if (( rc1==0 && rc2==0 )); ...` but that is what `if egrep -q first a.sh && egrep -q second a.sh; ...` does

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is that you're using the `[[` command. Use just the greps.

```
if egrep ... && egrep ... ; then
```